# Nginx ssl - SSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Tags: nginx, ssl

I am trying to enable ssl on a server using a certificate from 123-reg but I keep getting this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file("/opt/nginx/conf/cleantechlms.crt") failed (SSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line error:140DC009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib)
```

This is my nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name a-fake-url.com;
  root /file/path/public;   
  passenger_enabled on;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /opt/nginx/conf/cleantechlms.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /opt/nginx/conf/cleantechlms.key;
 }
```

I have tried setting my crt and key to full file permissions but there is no difference.

My crt file is the crt I was issued concatenated with the ca crt.

Update

I have tried copying both the keys in sperate files and then running 'cat mykey.crt >> ca.cert'

Also I tried manually copying the keys into the same file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `/opt/nginx/conf/cleantechlms.crt` is broken somehow. How did you create it? Could you post all steps you did?

Comment: In `cleantechlms.crt` you want to have only your public certificate without key and chain certificates from your ca. If you open it in text editor you should see just --BEGIN-CERTIFICATE-- blocks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for your help, this is how I solved it:

- Copy the certificates into a text editor to ensure there is no whitespace (I had already done this)
- Ensure the beginning and end certificate statements are on there own line and have the same number of '-' at each end.
- Ensure each line has 64 chars (except the last line)

Comment: I also got the error when the .cer file contained only the top level cert and not the entire bundled / chain of certs (intermediate and root ca)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with same exception and got it fixed by adding private key(x.509 + privatekey at the end) in the same pem file (pem format). I think its because I used to have the same format and validating the config with "nignx -t".

Hope it helps.